# Can I use WordPress' is_page() To change Content

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WordPress theme which doesn't support individual search page creation by category (status), which can be "A" or "B". If I create two pages, page1 and page2, can I use is_page function in functions.php to change the status value as the search page is displayed?. I need help with the following code:

```
if ( is_page('page1') {
               set status value to ='A';  ////This is the bit I'm struggling with.
        }
```

Comment: Yes you can use is_page in your function.php.

But what status do you want to change.

Comment: I want to change the variable $status with a value "A" ($status='A'). How do I set this?

Comment: Hi Shado, any further help on how I can accomplish this as I'm really stuck.

Comment: Hi, sorry - just stuck on a deadline. If I find anything I will let you know.